# R save plots with for loop (saving histograms works)

Tags: r, plot, save

I want to save 300 plots with a for loop but somehow the code works in the console but no plots are saved. I always get the following error:

```
Error in plot_list[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

If I plot histograms everything works just fine.

Here's my code:

```
plot_list = list()
for (i in 1:300) {
  p <-plot(matrix(1:15000, nrow = 15000, ncol = 50), datamatrix[1:15000,var_list[i,1]:var_list[i,2]], main = layer_list[[1]][i], xlab = "r [micrometer]")
  plot_list[[i]] = p
}

for (i in 1:300) {
  png(paste("plot", i, ".png", sep = ""), width = 1200, height = 750)
  plot(plot_list[[i]], main = substitute(paste('Layer ', a), list(a=layer_list[[1]][i])), xlab = "r [micrometer]", ylab = " Frequency")
  dev.off()
}
```

If I look at the plot_list, I get:

> plot_list

```
list()
```

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Third line of your code: `p <- plot(matrix ... `. otherwise  `p` is not known. BTW: why so complicated? Combine both loops ...

Comment: yes p is not defined

Comment: @J_F you're right, that's what I actually do. I still have the same error.

Comment: @J_F yes you're right. I guess I could combine the two loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to provide `datamatrix`, or at least `head(datamatrix)`.

As in the comments, you can do this is one loop and don't need to save objects to an intermediate list.

```
for (i in 1:300) {  
  png(paste("plot", i, ".png", sep = ""), width = 1200, height = 750)

  plot(matrix(1:15000, nrow = 15000, ncol = 50),
        datamatrix[1:15000, var_list[i, 1]:var_list[i, 2]],
        main = sprintf("Layer %s", layer_list[[1]][i]),
        xlab = "r [micrometer]",
        ylab = "Frequency")

 dev.off()
}
```